# Tomcat 6, JPA and Data sources

Tags: java, tomcat, jpa

I'm trying to get a data source working in my jsf app. I defined the data source in my web-apps context.xml

webapp/META-INF/context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/Sale">
<Resource auth="Container" 
   driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
   maxActive="20" 
   maxIdle="10" 
   maxWait="-1" 
   name="Sale" 
   password="admin" 
   type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/sale" 
   username="admin"/>
</Context>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<filter>
<display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
<filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
<dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
<session-timeout>
    30
</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>faces/welcomeJSF.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<context-param>
<param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
<param-value>ruby</param-value>
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

and my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="SalePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<non-jta-data-source>Sale</non-jta-data-source>
<class>org.comp.sale.AnfrageAnhang</class>
<class>org.comp.sale.Beschaffung</class>
<class>org.comp.sale.Konto</class>
<class>org.comp.sale.Anfrage</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

But no data source seems to be created by Tomcat, I only get this exception

```
Exception [TOPLINK-7060] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [Sale].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name Sale is not bound in this Context
```

The needed jars for the MySQL driver are included into the WEB-INF/lib dir.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: this might help http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1899677

Answer (score 6):

Your `<non-jta-data-source>Sale</non-jta-data-source>` does not look correct, you should use the format `<non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/ds/OracleDS</non-jta-data-source>` (at least this is my understanding of the documentation).

And I'm actually not convinced that your JDBC datasource JDNI resource is properly created (because you put the jdbc driver jar in `WEB-INF/lib`). From the Tomcat documentation:

> Use of the JDBC Data Sources JNDI
>   Resource Factory requires that you
>   make an appropriate JDBC driver
>   available to both Tomcat internal
>   classes and to your web application.
>   This is most easily accomplished by
>   installing the driver's JAR file(s)
>   into the `$CATALINA_HOME/common/lib`
>   directory, which makes the driver
>   available both to the resource factory
>   and to your application.

You should maybe test this first (by writing a quick piece of code doing a lookup to get a connection).

Also strictly follow the steps described in [EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Tomcat Web Tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Tomcat_Web_Tutorial) (and align the content of `web.xml`, `context.xml` and `persistence.xml`).

Comment: `<non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/Sale</non-jta-data-source>` given the `name="Sale"` in this question.

Answer (score 1):

As Josek has said you need to make a datasource reference on web.xml file:

```
    <resource-ref>
    <description>This is a PostgreSQL database connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/sadep</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

And the right way to call it is this:

```
javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/sadep");
```

So, for JPA using tomcat:

```
<non-jta-data-source>java:/comp/env/jdbc/sadep</non-jta-data-source>
```

Answer (score 0):

Think the web.xml also needs a reference to the datasource

```
<resource-ref>
  <description>DB Connection</description>
  <res-ref-name>Sale</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>  </resource-ref>
```

Comment: Thought the same, tested it too, but no affect. Anyway the Tomcat doc seems to be clear about that
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#context.xml%20configuration

Comment: How about this note "Note: docBase is very important - it must match your WAR file or you will get a (Name ds is not bound in this Context) exception " on this link http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Tomcat_Web_Tutorial#Non-JTA_Datasource